# how to get a class object of another apk

Tags: android

I want  to get a class object of another apk, But try these methods are still useless，For example, such：

```
PackageManager manager=getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName=new  ComponentName("com.access.test.out",  "com.access.test.out.ShowIInfoActivity");
ActivityInfo activityInfo=  manager.getActivityInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
Object obj= activityInfo.getClass();
```

But to obtain the `obj` object is empty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668665/accessing-classes-from-other-apk

Comment: The `obj` variable is definitely not "empty". It will hold `ActivityInfo.class`, because that is what `getClass()` will return for an `ActivityInfo` object.

Comment: very sorry ,I mean is the object obj object, not ShowIInfoActivity class,I want to get the class object ShowIInfoActivity ,please help me,  very thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not access code objects of other APKs.

Only one exception exists: If your APK is **signed by the same key** as the APK you want to access and the **same android:sharedUserId** has been set in both AndroidManifests you can access code objects of that specific APK.

Comment: very thanks, I want that do not need the ID case access it,it's  ok?